# ASP.NET Mobile Client Printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, bluetooth, handhelddevice

I have a simple asp.net page which contains data pulled from MySQL into four labels.
I want people to access the page from ANY handheld that can browse the internet, low end phones, high end smart phones etc.
Thing is as most mobile handhelds don't have the print function with the built in handset browsers I need to print those labels to a Bluetooth printer on the client side.

Is this even possible?
If it is, what should I Google, I have spent hours Googling various things with no luck.
Also, if it is not possible, what should I look at creating a page or web app like I need that will run on almost any handset available, without developing for say android or IOS only?
Also, if we can stick to c# if possible, if not, any advice will help.